# How do you get javascript eval to return a string and not a variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I recently posted asking how to pass databound data to a javascript function.   With help, I got the results I wanted; however, I ran into another problem immediately after.

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MECNUM") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="printer.png" OnClick="Display_OnClick"
                OnClientClick='<%# Eval("MECNUM", "Display_OnClientClick({0})") %>' />
```

Lets say that MECNUM came to be XYZ.  Unfortunately it throws an error, saying XYZ is an undefined variable.  What I really want is the string "XYZ" to be passed. Putting XYZ.toString() didn't work as the problem is still variable undefined.  Any thoughts?

```
    function Display_OnClientClick(mecnum) {
        alert(mecnum);
    }
```

Thanks a ton for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose that into double quotes . Like this.

`'<%# Eval("MECNUM", "Display_OnClientClick(\"{0}\")") %>'`

**Why you need to do this?**

If you don't do that it will generate javascript like this - `Display_OnClientClick(XYZ)`.
So clearly XYZ need to be either javascript variable or defined as javascript variable earlier. To cover up this, you need to have `Display_OnClientClick("XYZ")`. Here it will say that XYZ is a string and will work.That is the only reason here.

If you are facing issue with quotes escaping ( js error), you might refer this - [how to escape characters when using server side delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863822/how-to-escape-characters-when-using-server-side-delimiters)